# C# Stuck in StringBuilder loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, memory-leaks, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC web application using entity framework core to interact with a SQL database. Many of the pages are partially loaded using AJAX, but direct visits are possible (e.g. `www.example.com/some/actual/page`).

That is where the problem occurs. When a page is visited directly, a memory leak occurs with `StringBuilder`. See the picture below:
[image: StringBuilder memory leak]

Investigating further, it seems like there is some recursive loop it gets stuck in (This tree goes on, and on, and on, and on...):
[image: Recursive Loop]

I only explicitly use a `StringBuilder` in one spot, which I have already determined is unrelated to the problem. However, from my understanding, `JsonConvert` uses an underlying `StringBuilder`. I use `JsonConvert` primarily with converting session variable back into objects, and vice versa. Here's an example:

```
    public Cycle SelectedCycle
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(_selectedCycle)))
                return null;

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cycle>(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(_selectedCycle));
        }
        set
        {
            var serializedCycle = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(_selectedCycle, serializedCycle);
        }
    }
```

I want to say `ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` may be the cause of the problem, but I haven't been able to confirm that. What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?

**Update 1:**
`ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` does not seem to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hard code values in the code you have posted, see if the issue goes away. If yes, issue is elsewhere. If no, issue will be here and we can look deeper.

Comment: The Ignore value avoid the recursive serialization, so probably the error is not there, but just in case: did you try to set ReferenceLoopHandling to Error in order to see if the exception happens? This could confirm that the error occurs at this point, right?

Comment: Is it a leak or a big object? How fast does it grow? Do you receive an out of memory exception?

Comment: @GuillermoGerard I set it to error, and an error was thrown (as expected). Although, it was thrown as the application ran. I didn't even get the chance to directly navigate to a page. So, I would assume it's not the problem.

Comment: @Stefan It's definitely a leak and grows to 4GB in about a minute or so. I did not receive an out of memory exception. If I let it grow, it eventually eats up all my computer's RAM and I have to force shutdown my computer.

Comment: Hmm.. That's pretty fast, which *can* make it easier sometimes :-) ... Nevertheless, I think you should follow @CodingYoshi's advise. Maye a specific property uses a big object tree or is only appending (or perhaps doubled) each time. At this time it's hard to tell what's causing the error.

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the help! I'm in the processes of CodingYoshi's answer. It's a bit more complex in my application to "hard code values". There's a lot of underlying logic that has to be accounted for.

Comment: ... Most annoying part: when it turns out to be something else ;-) .. Oh, try them, one at a time.... nevertheless, good hunting!

Comment: StringBuilder instances are chained as the string grows bigger. Every StringBuilder has a default capacity of 8000 chars. That is, 16K of memory. This is consistent with what you're seeing. What you need to find out is what component is building such a big string.

Comment: Examining the string may shed some light on it... what's in it?

Comment: @KevinGosse So, that is part of the problem, I don't know where the `StringBuilder` that's growing is located. I only using `StringBuilder` explicitly at one point in my application. I've commented it out and still get the issue. That's what lead my research to possibly something with `JsonConvert`

Comment: What underlying logic? Simply return a new `Cycle` from the getter and creat one in the setter. Put a break point in both the setter and getter and if both present no error then all is good. What you set and return doesn't have to make sense.

Comment: @CodingYoshi So, a cycle is part of a nuclear power plant `Unit`, which is part of a nuclear power `Plant`. `Cycle`, `Unit`, and `Plant` are all session-variables. If they don't relate, the application will not run. I just have to do some database digging to get some that are related.